# JSON to List<string>

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I did not find solution for this simple question.
How can I convert Json like this:

```
{"States": ["Kansas","Oklahoma"]}
```

to List of strings in Unity

Comment: There's a lot of ways to parse a json formatted string into a c# object. What method would you like to use, what have you attempted?

Comment: In addition, what you have there is a JSON _object_, which contains a _property_ where the _value_ is an array. The JSON itself is not an array.

Comment: [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) `public class Root { public List<string> States { get; set; }}`=> `Root myDeserializedClass=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(YOURJSONHERE);`

Comment: @gunr2171 Any method suit me. How can i convert it to List<string>?

Comment: You've tagged this `C#`, `.NET`, and `Unity3D` and haven't included any of them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var json = "{\"States\": [\"Kansas\",\"Oklahoma\"]}";

    List<string> states = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<State>(json).States;


public class State
{
    public List<string> States { get; set; }
}
```

or this

```
List<string> states =JObject.Parse(json).ToObject<State>().States;
```